# Given $\theta(p)\neq p$ does there exist $q\leq p$, so that $\theta(q)q=0$?

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be a vN-Alg. Let $\theta\in \text{Aut}(\mathfrak{M})$. Let $p\in\mathfrak{M}$ be a projection, so that $\theta(p)\neq p$. Is there a projection $q\in\mathfrak{M}$ with $0\neq q\leq p$, so that $\theta(q)q=0$ (equivalently: so that $\theta(q)$ and $q$ are orthogonal projections). If not, why? If so, how does one show this? Is there a lemma/exercise somewhere for this?

Should this fail in general, does it at least hold, when either:

- $\frak{M}$ has faithful normal tracial state, $\tau$, and $\theta\in\text{Aut}(\frak{M},\tau)$;
- or furthermore $\mathfrak{M}=$ the hyperfinite II${}_{1}$-factor viewed with the usual trace?

Comment: Note that in the case, that attention be restricted to $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak{M},\tau)$, the above can only hold for properly outer automorphisms.* Thus the question should be modified to: **“Do all _outer_ automorphisms satisfy the above?”**

*(Since a $\theta\in\text{Aut}(\mathfrak{M},\tau)$ is properly outer, if and only if for each projection $p>0$ and $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ there is a subprojection $0<q\leq p$ with $\|\theta(q)q\|<\epsilon$.)